# UPDATE with subquery returning EMPTY/NULL MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, null, subquery

I have this database:

- table 1 Products: id, name, total_sales
- table 2 Products_sales: id_product, id_user, price

I want to update the column "total_sales" using this query

```
UPDATE products p SET total_sales = (SELECT SUM(price) AS totalPrice
FROM `products_sales` WHERE id_product = p.id GROUP BY id_product)
```

But if one product doesn't have any sale I get this error:

```
#1048 - Column 'total_sales' cannot be null
```

**How can I avoid this error when a product has no sales?**

Maybe using a fallback value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fallback you may use zero with `COALESCE`

```
UPDATE
    products AS p
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT id_product, COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) AS totalPrice
        FROM `products_sales`
        GROUP BY id_product
    ) AS pSub ON p.id = pSub.id_product
SET p.total_sales = pSub.totalPrice;
```

Comment: @BeaLovelace could you retry please - i joined with sub query